# pdflatex closes the PDF file when compiling

Tags: pdftex, viewers

I am using Linux Mint 18, compiling with `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016)` and Xreader to view PDF files.

Some days ago I observed that the viewer closes when I compile using TeXstudio. I asked about this on SourceForge and I got from Tim:

> ***Tim Hoffmann - 2016-09-28***
>
> This is on purpose. Some PDF viewers keep a file handle to the file
>   they display and thus would prevent generation of a new PDF during
>   compilation.
>
> Therefore, TXS closes external pdf viewers prior to a compilation.
>   This does only work with viewers opened from within TXS because they
>   are a subprocess we can control. We cannot influence viewers opened in
>   another way.

But today I observed that even if I compile from terminal with `pdflatex` the PDF viewer closes. This is annoying since I have to open it everytime after compiling.

Is there some change on `pdflatex`? TeXLive is updated.

Comment: Designed for Windows, by the sound of it. TeXStudio, I mean - not pdfTeX. This has zilch to do with pdfTeX or pdfLaTeX. So long as it can write to the requested file, the compiler doesn't give a monkey's. It doesn't know or care whether you even have a viewer, let alone whether you are using it. A viewer can interfere by locking the file on Windows. But the compiler only knows it can't write to the file. This is TeX Studio being designed for the LCD. This should be a preference if they want to support broken behaviour - not required.

Comment: Although the breaking of your workaround is presumably the viewer's fault as TeXStudio has nothing to do with it either.

Comment: @cfr, the Unix.SE link below in hbaderts' answer is the same. There is a bug with Xreader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `pdflatex` know nothing about your PDF reader. The only way<sup>[Citation needed]</sup> it can be influenced by the PDF reader is, if the reader has a lock on the PDF file, so `pdflatex` can not change it.

What you describe appears to be a [known bug](https://github.com/linuxmint/xreader/issues/25) in Xreader. Here is a [cross-site duplicate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/295400/xreader-closes-after-pdflatex-compilation) on Unix.SE, describing the same problem. The bug was fixed with [this commit](https://github.com/linuxmint/xreader/pull/28) on Github in July 2016. As there has been no release since June 2016 to this date, the only solution is to manually build Xreader from the sources.